# Error while Cassandra hector connection opening: "Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: cassandra, database-connection, hector

I'm trying to open a new connection and do updates as follows:

```
for(String str: queries){
    query = getQuery(str);
    TTransport tx_CUCR = getNewTransaction();
    try {
        System.out.println("opening...");
        tx_CUCR.open();
        CqlQuery<String, String, ByteBuffer> cqlQuery = new CqlQuery<String, String, ByteBuffer>(keyspace, StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), ByteBufferSerializer.get());
        cqlQuery.setQuery(query);
        System.out.println("executing...");
        QueryResult<CqlRows<String, String, ByteBuffer>> result = cqlQuery.execute();
        if (null != result) {
            rows = result.get();
        }
        System.out.println("flushing...");
        tx_CUCR.flush();
    } catch (HectorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        translateException(e);
    } catch (TTransportException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        tx_CUCR.close();
    }
}
```

where `queries` contain 0.5 million keys. While running through for loop, after few successful updates, it gets into following error while opening a new connection:

```
opening...
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at com.germinait.influence.cassandra.utils.CassandraUtils.executeQuery(CassandraUtils.java:546)
    at com.germinait.influence.cassandra.utils.CassandraUtils.updateByKey(CassandraUtils.java:484)
    at com.germinait.influence.cassandra.utils.IACassandraUtils.update(IACassandraUtils.java:298)
    at com.germinait.influence.cassandra.utils.IACassandraUtils.updateNodeScores(IACassandraUtils.java:274)
    at com.germinait.influence.cassandra.data.IACassBONodeScores.commit(IACassBONodeScores.java:94)
    at com.germinait.influence.facebook.db.updates.UpdateWithinGraph.initScores(UpdateWithinGraph.java:1048)
    at com.germinait.influence.facebook.db.updates.UpdateWithinGraph.initializePersonInfluenceScores(UpdateWithinGraph.java:981)
    at com.germinait.influence.facebook.db.updates.UpdateWithinGraph.applyInfluenceRankAlgo(UpdateWithinGraph.java:726)
    at com.germinait.influence.utils.IAUpdateUtils.runAlgorithm(IAUpdateUtils.java:296)
    at com.germinait.influence.NetworkIAMain.IA_runAlgorithm(NetworkIAMain.java:422)
    at com.germinait.influence.NetworkIAMain.main(NetworkIAMain.java:587)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
    ... 12 more
```

If I pause, while debugging, at exception for some time and then continue, it continues for few more next updates and completes successfully before resulting into this exception again at some another point.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Maybe you are overloading the server. What does Cassandra's log say?

Comment: I cannot see any `error` or `exception` in both `cassandra.log` and `cassandra.err` files...